# How to count the number of divs shown in each row when it depends on the screen resolution

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have the following code:

HTML

```
<div class="content" style="height: 30px;">
    <div class="content-box" id="myOptions">
        <div class="options-holder">
            <input type="checkbox" name="11111" id="Bob_111">
            <label for="111">Alex_1</label>
        </div>
        <div class="options-holder">
            <input type="checkbox" name="22222" id="Bob_222">
            <label for="222">Alex_2</label>
        </div>
        <div class="options-holder">
            <input type="checkbox" name="33333" id="Bob_333">
            <label for="333">Alex_3</label>
        </div>
        <div class="options-holder">
            <input type="checkbox" name="44444" id="Bob_444">
            <label for="444">Alex_4</label>
        </div>
        <div class="options-holder">
            <input type="checkbox" name="55555" id="Bob_555">
            <label for="555">Alex_5</label>
        </div>
        <div class="options-holder">
            <input type="checkbox" name="66666" id="Bob_666">
            <label for="666">Alex_6</label>
        </div>
        <div class="options-holder">
            <input type="checkbox" name="77777" id="Bob_777">
            <label for="777">Alex_7</label>
        </div>
        <div class="options-holder">
            <input type="checkbox" name="88888" id="Bob_888">
            <label for="888">Alex_8</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="button-wrapper"> <a href="#" class="toggle-trigger" id="showMoreButton" style="display:none;">
    <span data-collapse-text="Show less" data-expand-text="Show more" class="state up">Show more</span></a>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$.fn.myToggle = function () {
    return this.each(function () {
        var targetContainer = $(this),
            targetBox = targetContainer.find('.content'),
            targetTrigger = targetContainer.find('.toggle-trigger'),
            targetState = targetTrigger.find('.state'),
            contentBox = targetBox.find('.content-box'),
            boxHeight = contentBox.outerHeight(),
            optionHeight = targetBox.find('.options-holder').outerHeight();
        $(window).on('resize', function () {
            boxHeight = contentBox.outerHeight();
            if (targetState.hasClass('down')) {
                targetBox.stop(true, false).animate({
                    height: boxHeight
                });
            }
        });
        targetTrigger.on('tap', function () {
            targetBox.stop(true, false);
            if (targetState.hasClass('down')) {
                targetState.text(targetState.data('expand-text'));
                targetBox.animate({
                    height: optionHeight
                });
            } else {
                targetState.text(targetState.data('collapse-text'));
                targetBox.animate({
                    height: boxHeight
                });
            }
            targetState.toggleClass('up down');
            return false;
        });
    });
};
$(this.el).myToggle().on('click', '.checkbox-toggle', function (event) {
    var toggle = $(this),
        container = toggle.closest('.option-filter');

    event.preventDefault();
    container.find(':checkbox').prop('checked', toggle.hasClass('all'));
});
```

The problem is that the `.option-holder` divs don't fit in only one row in my `.content-box` div so i have to hide them and create a show more/less toggle button to show or hide the rest.

Everything works fine until the point that I only have the specific amount of `.option-holder` divs to fit only one line so i don't need the toggle button (the amount of divs comes dynamically from a server).

My current solution is to count the number of divs and show the toggle button only if they are more than 4 (in most screen resolutions i get 4 divs per row).
The problem is when the screen resolution is bigger and I get 5 or 6 per row.

If I have 6 divs per row but only 5 divs to show then the button still exists because I show it after 4 divs.

I know there are plenty easy fixes but I am not allowed to rewrite the code and change its logic so I have to find a way to count how many divs are shown each time in a row.

The code now works just by changing the height on div `.content` every time I click the button in order to show or hide the rest divs without giving the "not showing" divs any extra attributes e.g. `style="display: none;` to work with.

[image: before toggle]

[image: after toggle]

Any suggestions??

Comment: I know that my question is incomplete but unfortunately I am not allowed to post more code to make it work in JSFiddle. Sorry..

Comment: I just did and it doesn't work in my case..

Answer (score 3):

```
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('.options-holder'); //or getElementsByClassName... or just $('.options-holder').....
var x = divs.length;
var number_of_elements_in_first_row = 0;
for ( var i = 0; i < x; i++;) {
    if ( divs[0].offsetHeight !== divs[i].offsetHeight ) {
        divs[i].style.display = "none"; // hide divs[i]
        /* or if you need only number of elements per row
           add this instead hiding elements */
        number_of_elements_in_first_row = i;
        break;
    }
}

if ( divs[0].offsetHeight !== divs[x].offsetHeight )
    // add/show your MORE button... your function call
```

<strike>So, main idea is, if you have more than one row, last element will have different vertical position.</strike>

EDITED:
This code will go trough array of targeted divs and hide all divs that are not vertically aligned with the first one. This is not complete solution, more of idea how to handle this problem.

Comment: The problem is that my divs are not in two actual rows (as you can see from my html) so the divs.length just returns the total number of my divs.

Comment: Aaaa, I think I get it now. Your problem isn't just "should you show toggle button" but also what divs should you hide? I'll update my answer. Let me know have I understood you correctly this time :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var divs = $('.options-holder');

for(var key in divs){
    if (key > 0){
        if (divs[0].offsetLeft == divs[key].offsetLeft) {
            $("#showMoreButton").css("display", "block");
        }
    }
}
```

This is the solution needed as `.offsetLeft` is the same in every first div in each row..